# Mongoose filter by a property of multi related collection

Tags: mongoose

I have 2 collection types,
Collection a has a property that holds an array with objects from collection b

1. collection_a

```
{
  id:a1,
  collection_b: [b1,b2]
}
{
  id:a1,
  collection_b: [b2]
}
```

2. collection_b

```
{
  id:b1,
  isOpen:true
}
{
  id:b2,
  isOpen:false
}
{
  id:b3,
  isOpen:false
}
```

I need to query all objects from the collection a that at least one of the connected collection_b items property `isOpen` is set to true.

Here is the filter I have tried and not working:

```
{'collection_b.isOpen' : true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$lookup` with pipeline pass `collection_b` in let
- `$match` to check condition `collection_b` condition and `isOpen` condition
- `$group` by null and just return `id`, (its option) purpose of this stage to return the limited result from lookup to avoided memory exceed limit, if you are sure there are limited and countable documents then you can skip this stage
- `$match` to check return result from lookup is not empty
- `$project` to remove `collection_b_result` field its no longer needed

```
db.collection_a.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection_b",
      let: { collection_b: "$collection_b" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $in: ["$id", "$$collection_b"] } },
              { isOpen: true }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            id: { $first: "$id" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "collection_b_result"
    }
  },
  { $match: { collection_b_result: { $ne: [] } } },
  { $project: { collection_b_result: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/trMLu59_i9l)